# 'bower install angular-bootstrap' fails on OS X

Tags: bower, angular-bootstrap

I posted this question to the angular-bootstrap repo and was advised to talk to the bower folks...

Here's what happens when I try to use bower to install angular-bootstrap:

```
Charless-MacBook-Pro:orglines charlesames$ bower install angular-bootstrap
bower cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.12.0
bower validate 0.12.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
bower cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1 <1.3.0
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.36
bower resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.36
bower cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.12
bower validate 1.3.12 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.3.36

Additional error details:
Available versions: 1.4.0-build.3818+sha.030a42e, 1.4.0-build.3817+sha.898714d, 
[snip]
```

This is the only module I've tried that fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: Works on my machine. Try deleting `bower_components` and run it again. Does it work?

Comment: You could also try `bower cache clean` and then `bower install angular-bootstrap` again.

Comment: Cleaning the cache did not work, however when I attempted to install into a new clean project directory it worked fine.  I'm still confused, but I'm not stuck anymore.  Thanks!